# how to get the standard output from command in variable

Tags: bash, command-substitution

when we want to know what is the standard output of the ssh then we do

```
ssh  $linux_server "cat /proc/uptime"

[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && ssh is ok
```

but how to know the ssh standard output in case of the following?

```
 UPTIME=`    ssh $linux_server "cat /proc/uptime"  `
```

Comment: I don't understand..you have the STDOUT in `UPTIME` variable, so just use `"$UPTIME"`?

Comment: you mean to add [[ $? -eq 0 ]] , after the variable?   , (so it actually will be the same as example one? )

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your target.. You want to do the same check done with `$?` to `$UPTIME` too?

Comment: so the last command is ssh - do you agree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this with most shells (and therefore most portable) is with backquote (`) and since the arg you have to ssh does not need quoting, but the result probably would you'd write:

`` UPTIME="`ssh $linux_server cat /proc/uptime`" ``

or you can be specific to bash (and a few other shells, but not as universal as backquote) by using the $() as:

`UPTIME="$(ssh $linux_server cat /proc/uptime$)"`

Note that since backquotes use the same thing to delimit the command, they cannot be nested.  That's one of the advantages of the bash construct.  It also does not require forking a sub-shell for slightly more efficient execution.

Read the bash man page for more details.

Comment: The back tick has been obsolete for a long time, and back ticks can be nested in fact. There are no reasons to use back ticks, only reasons to abstain from using them. All Bourne shells use command substitution. The second line looks almost right, without the extra `$` character. `UPTIME="$(ssh $linux_server cat /proc/uptime)"`.